# How do I make a query calling from and to date values from date range picker?

Tags: sql, palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I am trying to filter a table on slate by doing this query

```
SELECT *
from "foundry_sync"."master_dataset" 
WHERE event_date >= ( {{w_date_range_picker.fromDateValue}} ) 
AND event_date <= ( {{w_date_range_picker.toDateValue}} )
```

But I am getting the error

```
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any idea on how to make such a call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date picker value has this format: `2023-03-14`.

If you click on the "Preview Rendered Query" button (little icon looking like an eye in the bottom right corner of your query window) you will see that when rendering a query it will be placed in that literal format into the query. Sql will then process that as an arithmetic operation and evaluate it into a number.

To avoid that you will need to add `'` `'` around the date picker value.
Additionally you will have to wrap the column name into `"` `"`.
That transforms your query into:

```
SELECT *
from "foundry_sync"."master_dataset" 
WHERE "event_date" >= ( '{{w_date_range_picker.fromDateValue}}' ) 
AND "event_date" <= ( '{{w_date_range_picker.toDateValue}}' )
```

If this doesn't fix your problem you can add explicit casting:
`CAST ('value' AS DATE)` or `CAST ("column_name" AS DATE)`